# CAS username field value to be manually added to the existing user on import?

Tags: user-input, cas, drupal-8

I installed the CAS module on a Drupal 8 site, and it is working fine. For new users, it auto-registers the user with cas_username, but I would like to import the cas_username manually for the existing Drupal 8 user.

I also tried importing users in CSV format(https://github.com/steveoliver/user_import); I have been able to add the $account(row[0],row[1]), but for the CAS username import, i don't know how to import it, and in which field is stored.

```
  'uid' => NULL,
  'name' => $username,
  'field_first_name' => row[0],
  'field_last_name' => $row[1],
  'pass' => $username,
  'mail' => $row[2],
  'status' => 1,
  'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'roles' => array_values($config['roles']),
```

I tried Managing CAS username; the suggestion given is for Drupal 7, but the same method doesn't work for Drupal 8.

Kindly suggest me solution import the cas username in CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution for the CAS_username import in CSV method. The method of db_insert in (authmap) table, which dynamically insert the CAS_username in respective field.

The authmap table is present in external authentication module.

```
db_insert('authmap')
->fields(array(
 'uid' => $uid,
 'provider' => 'cas',
 'authname' => $row[0],
 'data' => 'N;',
 ))
->execute();
```

So this is the method, i dynamically update the CAS_username using CSV. If any suggestions or update in that. Kindly Prescribe it.